# GridLayoutの子Viewから現在配置されているColumnとRowを取得する方法

Tags: android, java

タイトルのとおりです。

GridLayout上のViewを入れ替えるために、そのViewのColumnとRowを動的に取得したいです。
GridLayout.LayoutParamsなどから取得できるかと思ったのですが、そのようなメソッドも見つかりません。

座標から計算したり、Listenerにフィールドとして持たせるなどをする以外の方法はないんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まだ試してないですが、

交換対象の子ViewのgetLayoutParams()メソッドで取得したGridLayout.LayoutParamsのcolumnSpecとrowSpecを、それぞれ入れ替えるのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど！columnSpec=columnで、rowSpec=rowと考えて良いんでしょうか？

Comment: void swapViewOnGridLayout(View v1, View v2){
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (GridLayout.LayoutParams)v1.getLayoutParams();
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (GridLayout.LayoutParams)v2.getLayoutParams();
        GridLayout.Spec tempColumnSpec = params2.columnSpec;
        GridLayout.Spec tempRowSpec = params2.rowSpec;

        params2.columnSpec = params1.columnSpec;
        params2.rowSpec = params1.rowSpec;
        params1.columnSpec = tempColumnSpec;
        params1.rowSpec = tempRowSpec;
    }

Comment: `void swapViewOnGridLayout(View v1, View v2){
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (GridLayout.LayoutParams)v1.getLayoutParams();
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (GridLayout.LayoutParams)v2.getLayoutParams();
        GridLayout.Spec tempColumnSpec = params2.columnSpec;
        GridLayout.Spec tempRowSpec = params2.rowSpec;

        params2.columnSpec = params1.columnSpec;
        params2.rowSpec = params1.rowSpec;
        params1.columnSpec = tempColumnSpec;
        params1.rowSpec = tempRowSpec;
    }`このように交換してみたんですが、だめでした。。。

Comment: せっかくのLayoutParamsをsetするのを忘れていました。v1.setLayoutParams(params1);
        v2.setLayoutParams(params2);を入れたら成功しました。ありがとうございました！